# Show categories of 2 legends

Tags: highcharts, categories

I have a chart that has 2 legends. The `status` legend is created using the Highcharts api, and the `years` legend is external HTML which reloads the page with the number of columns per status as years are selected.

Most everything works fine, but one important thing I haven't been able to do is **show the year numbers under the columns**:
[image]

Instead, all that appears under the columns is the areas in which the statuses are applied (happens automatically with Highcharts):
[image]

I have the data - I know what years are supposed to appear, because I get them in the url. My only trouble is getting them under the columns.

How can I show the years under the columns?

Answer (score 1):

As I said, I have the data, and all I need is a means with which to enter it to the right place.

Thanks to the Highcharts detailed documentation (It's really awsome! ), and the flexibility of their api, I managed to find the dolution - and implement it - quite easily.

What I needed to understand was that I wanted to alter the [xAxis labels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels). Fortunately, Highcharts enables the [`formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) attribute, which enables customizing the labels to our hearts content:

```
formatter: function() {
    var ret = "";
    // get the relevant years from the "yid" parameter in the url:
    var yearsForColumn = getYidValFromUrl().split("_").sort().join(" "); 
    // show the original lbel value (this.value), and under that, show the years:
    ret = "<div style=\"text-align:center;\"><span>" + this.value + "</span><br><span>" + yearsForColumn + "</span></div>";
    return ret;
}
```